# Convert json to hash to insert with Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, activerecord

I'm still practising processing arrays and hashes, and particularly getting to details in 2d or 3d structures. I'm trying to use details in a json file to process some data ready to insert into the db with Active Record.

Here is my json structure for 'my_file.json'

```
# my_file.json    

[
  {
    "name": "Joe Bloggs",
    "telephone": "012-345-6789"
  },
  {
    "name": "Hilda Bloggs",
    "telephone": "012-345-6789"
  }
]
```

and here is the code I'm using to convert the json data into something I can insert into my db

```
   def json_insert_to_db
      require 'json'
      file = File.read('my_file.json')
      json_data = JSON.parse(file)
      details = json_data.map do |x|
        user = User.new
        user.name = json_data[x]['name']
        user.telephone = json_data[x]['telephone']
      end
    end
```

With this I get

```
NameError: uninitialized constant User
```

(User does exist in the database, by the way)

I can't work out where I'm going wrong, but I know it's something simple I am overlooking. Thanks for any help.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with `json`. Is `User` model declared in your code, or you expect Rails to write code for you?

Comment: Where does the "convert the json data" code snippet reside?  How do you run it?  It sounds like you might be running without having initialized the rails environment.  If it's a rake task, then you need to set the rails environment.

Comment: At the moment I am running it in the console. But I think I may have a problem with my db... :(

Comment: Please check if you have created the User Model first.If not create it and try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The User model was set up but my db had a migration issue. However, beyond that, at the time I was still unable to build what I needed when importing the json file.

I have now worked out how to do it. The migration issue was resolved and I also revised the structure of my json file first, for clarity.

```
# my_file.json    

{
  "new_users":
  [{
    "name": "Joe Bloggs",
    "telephone": "012-345-6789",
  },
  {
    "name": "Hilda Bloggs",
    "telephone": "012-345-6789",
  }]
}
```

And my script...

```
  require 'json'
  file = File.read('my_file.json')
  json_data = JSON.parse(file)['new_users']
  @new_users = json_data.each do |key,value|
    @new_user = User.new
    @new_user.name = key['name']
    @new_user.telephone = key['telephone']
  end

  @new_users.each { |x| puts x }
```